# Проверка заполненности поля JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Необходимо проверить заполненность полей и запретить отправку формы, если есть пустые

скопировал пример отсюда: https://www.howtomake.com.ua/front/simple-check-form-field-jquery.html , но почему-то вылетает ошибка(это не функция, хотя у него все работает):

> form.find('.empty_field').size();

пытался заменить на свое:

```
 if(form.find(".empty_field")){
     var sizeEmpty =1;
 } else {
     var  sizeEmpty =0;
 }

 alert(sizeEmpty);
```

но тогда даже если на странице нету элементов с таким классом, в переменную падает 1, что может быть не так?

Comment: Есть https://webref.ru/html/input/required и https://webref.ru/html/input/pattern

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fv18jr5b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.find(".empty_field")` - всегда будет возвращать объект, даже когда на странице не будет элементов с указанным селектором. Тоесть нет случая когда данная конструкция возвратит `false`. Вы можете проверять количество элементов на странице, например: `if(form.find(".empty_field").length > 0)`. Либо использовать плагин для валидации [jQuery Validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @GicO не забудте отметить ответ как верный

Answer (score 1):

Можешь дописать в html поля атрибут required

При добавление атрибута required, оно становится обязательным, если при нажатие на отправление формы оно не заполнено, будет выведено сообщение "Заполните это поле".

```
<input type="text" required>
```

Все работает без JS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var form = $('form');
form.on('submit', function () {
if(form.find(".empty_field").val().replace(/^\s+/, "").length == 0){
return false;

} // с проверкой на пробелы
else {
return true;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" class="empty_field">
<button>text</button>
</form>
```